# Laravel jobs seems to be running the same amount of times as position in queue

Tags: php, loops, laravel-5, queue, jobs

I am using Laravel jobs and don't know if this is default behaviour or I'm missing something.

In my controller I've ceated a simple `for` loop that runs 5 iterations and each iteration runs a job that logs that number.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Jobs\TestJob;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            TestJob::dispatch($i);
        }
    }
}
```

and in my job file I just log out the output

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class TestJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $count;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($count)
    {
        $this->count = $count;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        \Log::useFiles(storage_path() . '/logs/debug.log');
        \Log::debug('Running test' . $this->count);
    }
}
```

This is fair enough and does run how I expect. What I do not expect is the output. Why am I getting

```
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test0  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test1  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test1  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test2  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test2  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test2  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test3  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test3  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test3  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test3  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test4  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test4  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test4  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test4  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test4
```

instead of

```
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test0  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test1  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test2  
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test3    
[2018-05-13 07:50:23] local.DEBUG: Running test4
```

If I have other code in the handle instead of logging would that execute multiple times?

Comment: I've tried this with Laravel 5.5 and `beanstalkd` as the queue driver and it works just fine. It's probably something specific to your setup. More info about your setup and testing procedure would help.

Comment: I am using the database driver and laravel 5.4